# Which nosql db for loading billions of data

Tags: database-design, nosql, database-performance, in-memory-database

For storing billions of unstructed data on a daily basis , I would like to know which nosql db is preferred.the daily process is batch process with gigs of files as input.

Comment: are these logs? are these data going to be accessed often? anyway.. i think the answer to this question is only a google away!

Comment: These are not log . Input csv files

Comment: What types of searches is important? Please explain in-depth, it is so important. (please edit in you question-not in comments)